# gsutil getting stuck and asking for authentication

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I'm trying to copy a file from my Windows machine (already set up, and I've been using it regularly for gsutil) to copy a file, but it keeps telling me I'm trying to access protected data with no configured credentials.
Yesterday, though, it was running fine.

```
E:\studioProjects3\demo\rsalib\build\libs>gsutil cp rsalib-1.0.jar gs://dark-b
lade-365.appspot.com
Copying file://rsalib-1.0.jar [Content-Type=application/octet-stream]...
Uploading   gs://dark-blade-365.appspot.com/rsalib-1.0.jar:      0 B/4.14 KiB
Uploading   gs://dark-blade-365.appspot.com/rsalib-1.0.jar:      4.14 KiB/4.14 K
iB
You are attempting to access protected data with no configured
credentials. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/console#/project
and sign up for an account, and then run the "gcloud auth login"
command to configure gsutil to use these credentials.

E:\studioProjects3\demo\rsalib\build\libs>gsutil acl get gs://dark-blade-365.a
ppspot.com
You are attempting to access protected data with no configured
credentials. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/console#/project
and sign up for an account, and then run the "gcloud auth login"
command to configure gsutil to use these credentials.
```

I'm 100% sure that I own this project/bucket and it shows up on my developer console.

What I've tried so far:

- Running **gcloud auth login** to fetch a new token. I've already done this multiple times, and it's still given me the same exact error.
- Tried ensuring the project is the same as the bucket, and not the second project that I've also set up to have "authorized access" to the bucket.
- Tried rebooting my machine in case there was some environment issue
- Tried **gcloud auth revoke**, followed by **gcloud auth login** again.

None of these has resolved my issue. This is what **gcloud auth list** shows:

```
E:\studioProjects3\demo\rsalib\build\libs>gcloud auth list
Credentialed accounts:
 - yaraju@gmail.com (active)

To set the active account, run:
  $ gcloud config set account ``ACCOUNT''
```

Please help me figure out what's going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gsutil works fine from C:. But if I run it from E:\ it gets stuck and gives me that scary error message.

To fix:
Just run gsutil from any path on C:\ and give the absolute paths to whatever local paths you want to transfer from/to.

Comment: Just to add some information to your answer: This is a [known issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/238) which should be fixed in the future. 
In the meantime, the workaround is, as you said, running the command under C:\